# Base64 encoding different in script

Tags: bash, authentication, encoding, base64

I'm attempting to base64 encode a user:password string in a bash script, however the results in the script are different than if I run the command in a shell.

In shell (expected output):

```
echo -n "user:password" | base64
dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==
```

In script (w/ -n):

```
USER=$(echo -n "user:password" | base64)
echo $USER
LW4gdXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZAo=
```

In script (w/o -n, extra character at end):

```
USER=$(echo "user:password" | base64)
echo $USER
dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZAo=
```

Can someone tell me what I'm missing here. Thanks

Comment: Show your shebang and how do you run your script.

Comment: Can't reproduce w/ bash 4.4.20 and coreutils 8.28

Comment: Can't reproduce with dash, ksh, csh, zsh.

Comment: Ah yes, using printf is a great solution ,its behaviour is much less platform dependant than echo's

Comment: ```#!/bin/sh``` and I run it by ./script.sh. Using ```USER=$(printf "user:password" | base64)``` works

Comment: `#!/bin/sh` is the problem here. On most systems, it executes `bash` in a POSIX-compliant mode

Comment: [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/74329)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using a `#!/bin/sh` shebang, you're most likely asking `bash` (or whichever shell is behind `/bin/sh` which nowadays is almost always a link to another shell) to execute your script in a POSIX-compliant mode :

> If  bash  is invoked with the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of sh as closely as possible, while conforming to the POSIX standard as well.

Your problem is that POSIX `echo` does not define a `-n` flag, so it is understood in your command as just another parameter to display in your output. Indeed, `LW4gdXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZAo=` is the base64 encoding of `-n user:password`.

You should use `printf` instead of `echo`, whose behaviour is much better defined and varies less between implementations.

Moreover, unless you need your script to be portable and possibly run on platforms where `bash` isn't available, I suggest you use a `#!/usr/bin/env bash` shebang instead of your `#!/bin/sh` one so you get to enjoy the `bash` goodies.

Comment: Note that `printf` is a bit more complicated to use correctly than `echo` is. Its first argument is a format string that says how to format what it prints, and the rest are the actual things to print. In this case, I'd use `printf "%s:%s" "user" "password"` (although `printf "%s" "user:password"` would also work fine).